# Why isn't my hair moving

Tags: particles, hair

I was trying to create a hair particle animation.So I added an emitter with hair,checked the hair dynamics tab,tweaked few settings(internal friction,steps etc etc).Added a collider object(which is supposed to move the hair as it travels through them).Adjusted the soft body and cloth settings tab in collision,and also gave it a force field with strength about 200.Still the hair  do not move(I'm not bald btw.haha).Whys is it happening,if anyone have any idea please do suggest.Thanks.

ok here's the link man;

[image]

Comment: Did you bake it?

Comment: I didn't earlier but I did baked after you suggested and still no effect.Actually something weird happened the hair particles diasppear as soon as the collider touches the hair.

Comment: I would remove force field, is your collider object 3-d /manifold (as opposed to 2d like a plane)

Comment: its a sphere and i did removed the force field still nothing.

Comment: Hard to say without looking at it.  Post a link to the blend if you can.  Also hair collision is a known weirdness area for blender, and the code is being completely rewritten.  I can almost always get the effect I'm after, but it may involve some creative workarounds.

Comment: ok i did man,see if you find anything weird.

Comment: It seems that if the emitting plane is perfectly flat and the normals point up on global z, the sim barfs possibly all forces canceling out?.  I changed a bunch of stuff, have a look.  Make sure to Click 'free bake' and then 'bake' -- major parameters: stiffness, mass, segments, damping....
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3008" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3008/)